# can we call a user defined function in MySQL range based partition

Tags: mysql

can we used user defined function when create range based partition in mysql 5.5.20 ?

I create a function which is basically extract month from timestamp , now i want to call this function along with range partition

Comment: And you haven't tried it or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for the question. 
No We Can't use user defined function while creating partitioning .

Below is the  MySQL Docs Link which describe limitation of MySQL partitioning .
.
Url : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html